# Laravel 5.1 PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm new to coding and Laravel 5.1, and after watching the tutorials by Laracasts I have been creating my own webpage. I came across and error that I cant fix...

> Method [send] does not exist.

My code looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller
{

    /**
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function emailContactForm (Request $request){
        $msg = $request->input('message');
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max 500',
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);
        //
        Mail::send(
            'emails.contactForm',
            [
                'message'=>$msg,
                'name'=>$name,
            ],
            function($m) use ($email) {
                $m->to('jessica.blake@autumndev.co.uk', 'say hi')
                    ->subject('new message')
                    ->from($email);
            }
        );
        //
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the `mail` function, which we have now got working, but the send still doesn't? Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: Full stack trace as per laravel log file: http://pastebin.com/ZLiQ7Wgu

Comment: can you please post full error stack?

Comment: @pinkalvansia added as a paste bin link

Comment: This is `route` related issue and not `Mail::send()`. can you please post `route.php` contents?

Comment: What kind of request are you making? GET/POST?

Comment: @pinkalvansia it was a route issue, seemed I had sent the route to at send, which was causing the issue, thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

Answer (score 1):

At the very first sight, you are calling the **controller method** `send()` but you actually named it `emailContactForm()`

You dont post routes and actions so the quick fix by now is trying to rename `emailContactForm` to `send`, despite instead you should probably need to review all your related routing logic.